# iframe location loading observation

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

I want to check an iframe location when it got changed by user (e.g. by clicking on a link). So I figured out this might work:

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  alert(event.originalTarget.location);
}, true);
```

For some reason `event.originalTarget` doesn't have a location.

My question: How do I access the location?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the window-object represented by the iframe instead of the DOM-node to retrieve the location:

```
this.contentWindow.location
```

Note: The access to the iframe ist restricted by same-origin-policies, so if the user will navigate to an adress on a different domain/subdomain, you won't get any information about that.